# Convergence with distance $d$ implies convergence with distance $d'$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Let $E$ be a space and $d$ and $d'$ be two distances on $E$ with the property that $U$ open with $d$ implies that $U$ is open with $d'$. Show that if $x_n$ converges to $x$ with $d'$, then $x_n$ converges to $x$ with $d$.

Just to clarify, the property means that for a ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$ contained in $U$, if $d(x,x_0) < r$ implies $d'(x,x_0) < r$ for any $x_0$ in the ball, correct? Would this imply that $d'(x,x_0) < d(x,x_0)$ for all $x$ and $x_0$? Aside from that, I'm not sure where to go with this, so any pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your assumption says that $\mathcal{T}_d$ (the topology generated by the $d$-balls) is a subset of $\mathcal{T}_{d'}$ (ditto for $d'$). Now if $x_n \to x$ under $d'$, we have $x_n \to x$ under $d$: Let $r>0$ and consider $B(x,r) \in \mathcal{T}_d$, then $B_d(x,r)$ is thus open in the $d'$-topology and a $d'$-neighbourhood of $x$ and so, by convergence under $d'$, from some $N$ onwards we must have $x_n \in B_d(x,r)$, and so $\forall n \ge N: d(x_n, x) < r$, and we are done.

Having more open sets makes convergence a stronger property.

Answer (score 1):

$x_n$ converges to $x$ implies that for every open set, $U$, that contains $x$, there exists $N\in\Bbb{N}$ such that for all $n> N$, $x_n$ lies in $U$. As open sets induced by both the metrics are the same, the choice of metric doesn't alter the convergence criteria.

Comment: The assumption is *not* that the topologies are the same!

Answer (score 1):

Let U be any open set in (E,d) containing x. Then by given condition U is open in (E,d'). Since x_n converges to x in (E,d'), then there exist a natural number k such that x_n in U for all n greater equal to k.

We choose U arbitrary open set containing x in (E,d). Hence x_n converges to x in (E,d).